# What to do with plastic wrap that has 'Allah' on it?

Tags: quran, mushaf

I have a Quran mus'haf on the front cover it has 'Allah' in plastic material cutout and over it is plastic wrap (or thick cling film) 'Allah' over it that fell off. I'm not sure what to do with it, I can't stick it back on the cutout. What can I do with it? Someone said since it's just cling film then I can just cut it up wrap it in tissue and discard it. Is that right? I don't want to do anything wrong or haram.